# Change name of cross reference table in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables that have a many-to-many relationship to each other, `User` and `Role_LKP`. In `User`, I have:

```
public virtual ICollection<Role_LKP> Roles { get; set; }
```

And in `Role_LKP`, I have:

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

In the database I have `User_Role_XREF` however LINQ attempts to access `dbo.UserRole_LKP`. I cannot change the name of this table; is it possible to tell LINQ what the name of the XREF table is without creating an entity for User_Role_XREF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out from [a marginally related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653179/how-to-use-linq-to-join-entity-tables-with-a-cross-reference-table). Based on this code I think it's unlikely you can do this via a data annotation, which would be cleaner, but you can edit the context in the following way to achieve the desired effect:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilding.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(r => r.Roles)
        .WithMany(u => u.Users)
        .Map(ru =>
        {
            ru.ToTable("User_Role_XREF", "dbo");
            ru.MapLeftKey("User_ID");
            ru.MapRightKey("Role_ID");
        });
}
```